# How to set the HTML Entity (decimal) and HTML Entity (hex) in XmlElement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I would like insert entity in XmlElement.InnerText, but I am getting the error,

How to set the HTML Entity (decimal) and HTML Entity (hex)?

```
    foreach (XmlElement aNode in loadXML.SelectNodes("//w:sym", nsmgr))
    {
      //i cannot be reset the value with entity;
      aNode.InnerText="&#x3B1;";//or
      aNode.InnerText="&#945;";
     }
```

Comment: "but I am getting the error" - please specify what error you are getting, and also what resulting XML you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Unicode as a hex number you can use e.g. `aNode.InnerText = '\u03B1';`. Or of course you can directly write `aNode.InnerText = "α";`.

If you really want to use numeric character reference then set `InnerXml`, not `InnerText`: `aNode.InnerXml = "&#x3B1;";`.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, Yes, I tried those three ways what you suggested, i would expect output xml: <w:sym>&#x3B1;</w:sym> not "<w:sym>α</w:sym>".

Comment: No, the DOM tree stores text nodes with Unicode characters, not character references. So unless you serialize or save the DOM tree with an encoding that does not contain the `α` character you won't get a character reference back. And of course you would get character references for all characters not representable in the chosen encoding. Preserving character references is not possible with most tree representation of XML, like XmlDocument or XDocument.

Comment: "Save the DOM tree with an encoding" how to save encoding with unicode reference? please help me!